# How to tell if html video is currently playing

Tags: testing, video, automated-tests, web-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to test if an Html video is currently playing, but can't seem to figure out how to get the `currentTime`. I've been trying things like:

```
async videoIsPlaying(indexOfVideo = 0) {
    return ClientFunction(() => {
        const video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[indexOfVideo];
        return video.currentTime > 0;
    });
}
```

but my expect:

```
await t.expect(await playerPage.videoIsPlaying()).eql(true);
```

is returning:

`AssertionError: expected [Function: __$$clientFunction$$] to deeply equal true`

What am I doing wrong? Also, I'm using `.eql()` because `.ok()` returns truthy for any result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahhh... just needed to *fire* the function, and also pass in the index thusly...

```
async videoIsPlaying(indexOfVideo = 0) {
    return await ClientFunction((indexOfVideo) => {
        const video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[indexOfVideo];
        return video.currentTime > 0;
    })(indexOfVideo);
}
```

*Just FYI, this function lives in a page object*